# changing inner array object value with outer array value with map

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I'm new to full-stack development, specifically to java-script and functional programming. 
Using high-order function (like map, filter and so) I need to change inner object array values into the outer array given value:

```
let arr = [
[ [ 
  {name: "Alice", age: 22},
  {name: "Charlie", age: 35}
 ], "Bob" ],
 [ [
  {name: "John" , age: 42}
  ], "Ben"]
]
```

and I need output array of:

```
output = [
 [ 
  {name: "Bob", age: 22},
  {name: "Bob", age: 35}
 ],
 [ 
  {name: "Ben", age: 42}
 ]
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already knew to use `map`, so here it is:

```
arr.map(x => x[0].map(y => {return {...y, name: x[1]}}))
```

For each item of the main list, we map it to a list of objects with the name replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified Simon's answer. Added a little bit of destructuring sugar

```js
let arr = [
[ [ 
  {name: "Alice", age: 22},
  {name: "Charlie", age: 35}
 ], "Bob" ],
 [ [
  {name: "John" , age: 42}
  ], "Ben"]
]

const result = arr.map(([data, name]) => data.map(({age}) => ({name, age})))

console.log(result)
```